# How to manually trust an SSL certificate to a development server?

Tags: ssl, certificate, version-control

On our development server, we are using a self generated SSL certificate, so every time I browse to the dev site, IE panics and asks me if I wanted to continue. How can I manually add the dev certificate to my local workstation so IE wouldn't panic?

Furthermore, I really wanted to be able to commit source code to the dev machine through SourceSafe Remote Plug-in, which requires a valid certificate to work. As much as I love to, choosing a different SCM is not an option.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this :

Visit your site in Internet Explorer.
Click on Continue to this website (not recommended)
Click on Certificate Error in the red colored address bar
Click on View certificates
In the Certificate dialog, press Install Certificate
In the Certificate Import Wizard, click Next
On page 2 of the wizard, select Place all certificates in the following store and click Browse;
In the Select Certificate Store dialog, select Trusted Root Certification Authorities, click OK 
In the wizard, click Next, click Finish
If a security message pops up, choose Yes

That should make VSS also see it as valid and thus happy.

Comment: worked for me, tyvm